# Run Butterknife samples on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, butterknife

I try to run Butterknife project samples on Android studio 1.2 and keep getting that issue : 
"Error:Android Source Generator: [butterknife-sample] AndroidManifest.xml file not found"

If I try to run the SimpleActivity, same issue : AndroidManifest.xml doesn't exist or has incorrect root tag.

Any idea